# pyinstaller cant find goose file path

Tags: python, pyinstaller, goose

**Question**

Why will Pyinstaller not work with `goose` files? Is it an issue with the executable creator or my code?

**Code**

```
from goose.Goose import Goose
url = 
'http://sociedad.elpais.com/sociedad/2012/10/27/actualidad/1351332873_157836.html'
g = Goose({'debug':False,'enableImageFetching': False,'localStoragePath':'./tmp'})
article = g.extractContent(url=url)
#article.title
print article.cleanedArticleText[:150].encode("utf8","ignore")
```

**Error Log From Pyinstaller**

My program, created with pyinstaller, fails to find goose files in this path:

```
IOError: Couldn't open file C:\Users\user\Desktop\dist\main.exe?118272\goose/resources/text/stopwords-en.txt
```

This happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\build\pyi.win32\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\goose.Goose",line 52, in extractContent
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\build\pyi.win32\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\goose.Goose",line 59, in sendToActor
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\build\pyi.win32\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\goose.Crawler", line 86, in crawl
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\build\pyi.win32\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\goose.extractors", line 245, in calculateBestNodeBasedOnClustering
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\build\pyi.win32\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\goose.text", line 97, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\build\pyi.win32\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\goose.utils",line 76, in loadResourceFile
  IOError: Couldn't open file C:\Users\user\Desktop\dist\main.exe?118272\goose/resources/text/stopwords-en.txt
```

What's wrong?

Comment: May you please add your Python code, so that we can attempt to copy your error?

Comment: look code ^  on dpaste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though `goose` requires data files in addition the Python source for normal operation. eg.  It looks up `goose/resources/text/stopwords-en.txt`.  When you freeze the Python app with PyInstaller, if `goose` looks in the standard filesystem locations for its resource files they will not be present since when you create an executable with PyInstaller, all of the files are within the installer.

So, you have to tell PyInstaller to add these extra resources to your executable, then modify the `goose` code to obtain its resources from an alternate location when run from the the exe generated by PyInstaller.

Details are in the PyInstaller manual under the [Accessing Data Files](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#id10) heading.

Comment: i try all method load files, maybe i try wrong, but it does not help